# Symfony 2, getting an error when trying to execute doctrine 2 commands

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting an error when trying to execute any doctrine 2 commands (even when trying to execute "help" or "list" commands).
It has been working okey till i tried to create a new Repository class. Since that moment, i only get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Notice: Undefined index: algorithm in C:\Archivos de programa\PostgreSQL\En
>     terpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\SymAhorro\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfon
>     y\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension.php line 444

Does someone know which can be the problem?

Comment: "Does someone know which can be the problem?" - yeah, your repository class.

Comment: Indeed, my Repository class was not created, but since my "try" of creating it, i get this error.

Comment: did you check algorithm  column?

Comment: @GunnerAziz, i am not sure what algorithm column you are refering to, but i created a new Symfony project, moved all the classes, files, etc... to the new project folders and everything works okey, even the supposed "wrong" Repository class.

Comment: Undefined index: algorithm I was mentioning to this

Comment: Sorry, right, i checked the SecurityExtension.php file looking for it, althought that was a Symfony file and i havent modified it. Anyway, i didnt see anything remarkable, but, as i said, it is not my own file and dont know exactly how it works.